# Submit a POST form in Cypress and navigate to the resulting page

Tags: request, xmlhttprequest, response, cypress

I'm having issues with Cypress loading the response body when I utilize the cy.request() command.

In our application, when a form is filled out and submitted, it POSTs, and the response body is the new page.

When I'm trying to do in Cypress is programmatically fill out the form. So I set up a cy.request() command, with the body filled with the form fields, which is the same as what happens when you fill it out manually. When I run the command, I can view the console and see that the correct body is being returned, but the new document page doesn't load. So I'm left just sitting on the old empty form page.

```
cy.request({
        url: "company-webpage-form-url.com",
        method: "POST",
        form: true,
        body: {
            first_name: "first_name",
            last_name: "last_name",
            company_name: "company_name",
            address1: "address1",
            address2: "address2",
            city: "city",
            state: "NY",
            zip: "13903",
            country: "US",
            phone_number: "607-555-5555",
            phone_ext: "555",
            fax_number: "fax_number",
            fax_ext: "fax_ext",
            email: "developer@company.com",
            email_2: "developer@company.com",
            user_data: "Continue"
        }
    });
```

All of the data is correct, and I get the correct response body, but I can only see it in the console. I have no idea how to get it to load, like it would when I submit the form. All I get right now is a 200 response, and the test ends.

I've tried visiting the next URL right after, but I get an error that the page for that URL doesn't exist. I've tried clicking the submit button after the POST, but that just results in an empty form being submitted, which causes a validation error.

I'm at a loss for how to get cypress to load the response body, which is in the form of a document (the new page). Anyone have any tips?

Edit: I should add that - the reason I am looking to fill the form from a POST is because the form is necessary to fill out for me to test whether certain options work or not. I have a single test that ensures the form fields and submission work as required, but for the 30+ options that need to be checked on the other side of this form, I wanted to follow Cypress' best practice of not manually filling the form every single time (they show an example with login on the website).

Comment: Why did you expect otherwise? You're not making the request through the *page*, there's no request being made that might change what you see in the browser. Fill the form out **as a user would**.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to follow the best practices of not bogging down my tests by manually filling out a form in every single test I have. Cypress explicitly states that it's against the best practices, so, in trying to follow their advice and not needlessly test one feature on the interface 30 times past the initial manual run, I am searching for a solution that aligns with those best practices and speeds up our testing.

Comment: *"on the website"* - this is the internet, please give an actual link to what you're referring to. You haven't given enough information about the actual app you're testing to say whether this could be made to work, but what you're currently attempting definitely won't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'd like to simulate a form POST navigating to a new page, you can use [`cy.visit()`](https://on.cypress.io/visit) to do this! Just change your `request` to `visit` and it should work:

```js
cy.visit({
        url: "company-webpage-form-url.com",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
            first_name: "first_name",
            last_name: "last_name",
            company_name: "company_name",
            address1: "address1",
            address2: "address2",
            city: "city",
            state: "NY",
            zip: "13903",
            country: "US",
            phone_number: "607-555-5555",
            phone_ext: "555",
            fax_number: "fax_number",
            fax_ext: "fax_ext",
            email: "developer@company.com",
            email_2: "developer@company.com",
            user_data: "Continue"
        }
    });
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could structure a cy.visit() command like this, but this is exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you!

I'm still a bit new to developing, so articulating what I was looking for was a bit hard, so thank you for this solution. It's on point.

Comment: This is cool, I didn't know you could do that, but note that this couples your E2E tests to the underlying data structure. That's probably not a great idea, but YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

[`cy.request()`](https://on.cypress.io/request) is intended to be used for accessing APIs to set up your tests, it does not interact with the application under test or the DOM at all.

If you want to test form submission, use [`cy.get()`](https://on.cypress.io/get), [`cy.type()`](https://on.cypress.io/type), and [`cy.click()`](https://on.cypress.io/click) to interact with the form like a real user would:

```js
// fill out a form field
cy.get('input[name="first_name"]')
.type('first name here')
.get('input[name="last_name"]')
.type('last name here')
/** fill out more form fields **/

// simulate clicking submit
cy.get('input[type=submit]')
.click()
```

Comment: I am trying this aproach, but after submitting the form, weird redirect happens, instead of landing on the next page like normaly I endup on the login page, the default page. How could this be? Looks like the submit button works differently in normal browser and in cypress. https://prnt.sc/um4hmt