# how to test submitted data in Cypres

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to check if some values in submitted data have expected values. To do this i tried to access and sent data by XMLHttpRequest in Cypress during the request run.

```
    describe('test submitted data', () => {
      it('some data is changed', () => {
        submitBtn().click({force: true});
        
        //in this case Cypress doesnt get into this debugger point
        cy.server({
          onAnyRequesty: (props) => {
            debugger
          }
        });

        //in this one Cypress go into and stops at the point but
        //the data variable doesnt contrain submitedData
        cy.route('PUT', `${APP_CONTEXT}/api/model/${modelId}`, (data) => {
          debugger;
        });
      });
    });
```

Data is sent by the way below:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "PUT",
        data: "{"inputData":"123"}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: () => {},
        error: () => {}
      });
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks

**One more thing**: and how to make Cypress check if the data condition is met? for example:

```
it('some data is changed', () => {
        submitBtn().click({force: true});
        cy.route('PUT', `${APP_CONTEXT}/api/model/${modelId}`, (data) => {

          const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
          // the test is passed if the value is equal
          expect(parsedData.inputData).to.eq('123');
        });
```

**UPDATE**

i tried proposed answer from @richard-matsen and different callBack keys but neither were working:

- onResponse
- onAnyResponse
- onRequest
- onAnyRequest

But callback function in neither of them didnt run

```
      it("Signature removed from the field and empty value submitted", () => {
        cy.server();
        submitBtn().click();

        //here i check the put url as an url submitting to
        cy.log(`${BASE_URL}/api/data/${formId}/${modelId}`);

        cy.route({
          method: "PUT",
          url: `${BASE_URL}/api/data/${formId}/${modelId}`,
          onAnyRequest: (data) => {
            const signValue = JSON.parse(data)[`${modelId}|sign_2||`];
            debugger;
            cy.log(signValue);
            expect(signValue).to.eq(null)
          }
        })
      })
```

**UPDATE UPDATE**
@richard-matsen ,thanks, you were right, I did an error in method options, but I decided to simplify the route options but still the debugger cannot get in neither handler:

```
      it("Submitted data", () => {
        cy.server({ whitelist: (xhr) => console.log('custome log: server', xhr) });
        submitBtn().click({force: true});

        cy.route({
          url: /.+/,
          onResponse: (data) => {
            debugger;
            cy.log('onResponse signature value - ' + data);
          },
          onAnyResponse: (data) => {
            debugger;
            cy.log('onAnyResponse signature value - ' + data);
          },
          onRequest: (data) => {
            debugger;
            cy.log('onRequest signature value - ' + data);
          },
          onAnyRequest: (data) => {
            debugger;
            cy.log('onAnyRequest signature value - ' + data);
          }
        })
      })
```

Also tried to click submission btn right after cy.route, but that wasn't working as well.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: one more useful cypress chat to find some help https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress#

Answer (score 0):

The patterns for using `cy.route()` are

- cy.route(url)
- cy.route(url, response)
- cy.route(method, url)
- **cy.route(method, url, response)**
- cy.route(callbackFn)
- cy.route(options)

Looks like your command is interpreted as #4, but `response` is the value used to stub. Never seen it with a function, so is best guess.

To be sure, use the [pattern with options](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Options) and put function in `onResponse`

```js
cy.route({
  method: 'PUT', 
  url: `${APP_CONTEXT}/api/model/${modelId}`, 
  onResponse: (data) => {
    expect(parsedData.inputData).to.eq('123');
  }
})
```

Also `onAnyRequesty: (props) =>` change to `onAnyRequest: (props) =>`.

---

In your latest code,

```js
onAnyRequest: (data) => {,
```

data is already parsed so `JSON.parse(data)` causes an error.

In my test, I get a weird error about cross-origin when trying to re-parse within `onResponse()` (Expecting a message like 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1').

In any case, put the debugger up one line to avoid other code problems.

---

If cy.route() is not matching the url, you can see all calls with (temporary)

```js
cy.server({ whitelist: (xhr) => console.log('server', xhr) }).
```

Maybe APP_CONTEXT !== BASE_URL?

---

Submit can be a native event which won't be captured by Cypress.

I think you can test if this is so, see [Submit a POST form in Cypress and navigate to the resulting page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56497559/4716245).

If you do the following instead of `submitBtn().click({force: true})` and the `cy.route()` does pick it up, then you have a native event.

```js
cy.visit({
  url: `${BASE_URL}/api/data/${formId}/${modelId}`,
  method: "PUT",
  form: true,
  body: {
    inputData :"123"
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but Cypress doesnt go into callback function, could you see the updated question, please

Comment: thanks for your help, ```cy.server({whitelist...``` really was helpful but Cypress still cannot step in the route handlers :(

Comment: In 2nd update, `submitBtn().click({force: true});` should be after `cy.route()`, because this command is a listener, it must be configured before the event occurs.

Comment: But another thing, submit is often a native event and Cypress does not capture those yet. If you see the PUT coming from the whitelist logging, I'm pretty sure it's not native event and `cy.route()` should catch it.

Comment: One more thing, using a very general url pattern might be bad - reason is I have 20+ GET's in my app but only the first few are being caught. I recall (was on older version of Cypress) that some sort of limit is in place. Will see if can find the info.